# Calculate Number of Months and Days until Birthday

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets, match, datediff

I have a list of everyone's birthdays like below where `today` is `2022-09-09`.

```
Birthday
January 15
July 1
December 25
```

How do I create a formula in google sheets where regardless of the year, I can figure out how many months are days are left before the birthday values?

It gets tricky because July 1 we know has already passed since it is September.

I would like to ideally do this in google sheets.

Comment: Is this not an appropriate question then if I am asking for a formula to show this answer? Something like `today()-date`? It's more complicated than that since we shouldn't take years into account

Comment: This question was linked in [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420294/is-this-question-regarding-google-sheets-off-topic-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
 DATEDIF(TODAY(), A2:A4, {"M", "MD"}), 
 DATEDIF(TODAY(), YEAR(A2:A4)+1&TEXT(A2:A4, "-mm-dd"), {"M", "MD"})))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

**Use this formula**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,
 DATEDIF(TODAY(), 
         IF(
              DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),
      MONTH(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"", "([A-Za-z].+?) ")&1),
      REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"", "[0-9]+"))<=TODAY(),
              EDATE(
              DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),
      MONTH(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"", "([A-Za-z].+?) ")&1),
      REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"", "[0-9]+")),12),
              DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),
      MONTH(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"", "([A-Za-z].+?) ")&1),
      REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"", "[0-9]+"))), {"M", "MD"})))
```

[image]